# Default value of PixelFormat for Graphics.TBitmap in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tbitmap

What is the default value of PixelFormat for TBitmap in Delphi?
Do I need to specify PixelFormat everytime I create TBitmap?

For example,

```
var
  img: TBitmap;
begin
  img := TBitmap.Create;
  img.PixelFormat := pf32bit; // or pf24bit?
  ...
  ...
end;
```

Comment: This could be answered by a short look at the source. If you like to have a specialized instance, build a factory for that purpose

Comment: Interesting, source does not match the docs. [Docs say](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.DDBsOnly) the default handle is DIB, in actuality a TBitmap is by default a DDB, hence pixel format is pfDevice. And no, you do not need to specify pixel format. ..unless you do..

Comment: This could be answered very easily with a breakpoint in the debugger on the `img.PixelFormat` line, running to the breakpoint, and then inspecting the value of `img.PixelFormat` before the line executes. (It would contain the default value at that point.)

Comment: the default value is pfDevice (equal to zero).

Comment: @DoctorLai: Then you have the answer to your question - the default value is `pfDevice`, and if you want it to be something other than that for an image you create, you have to change it yourself.

Comment: *Do I need to specify PixelFormat everytime I create TBitmap?* I don't know. Do you? It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default value is pfDevice (equal to zero).